# How do I keep a value within QLineEdit to retain its value after program is closed?

Tags: ruby, qt, qt4

I am using Qt Ruby

How do I keep the value of a user entered QlineEdit to keep its state even after the program is closed, in that way, the user can access the contents the next time he opens the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1 - using File.write/read:**

```
edit_widget = Qt::LineEdit.new(parent)
File.write(filename, edit_widget.text)
exit
```

After the program re-start:

```
text = File.read(filename)
edit_widget.setText text
```

**Solution 2 - using QSettings:**

```
settings = Qt::Settings.new(filename, Qt::Settings::NativeFormat)

edit_widget = Qt::LineEdit.new(parent)
edit_widget.text = "abcde"

settings.setValue("field1", Qt::Variant.fromValue(edit_widget.text))
settings.sync
exit
```

After the program re-start:

```
settings = Qt::Settings.new(filename, Qt::Settings::NativeFormat)
edit_widget = Qt::LineEdit.new(parent)
edit_widget.text = settings.value("field1").toString
```

Comment: Actually I have Main menu screen. On click of button, second screen opens up and has  around 20 Widgets (LineEdit's). What I want is after closing the entire application , the next time I open Main menu and click on the button there, second screen with 20 widgets should have the data user had entered the previous time.

Comment: I read somewhere that QSettings can be used. Is it applicable in this case? If so, how should I apply in this scenario ?

Comment: Using QSettings is possible. Did you check the Qt Documentation, online or inside the Qt Assistant? The "QSettings: Basic Usage" section should get you started.

Comment: Yes I tried searching online and I find only Qt and C++ used everywhere. Hardly any sources for Qt and Ruby. Hence had to post it here after several tries of doing it in different methods

Comment: See above. There is not enough documentation available for qtruby. You need to learn translating the C++ examples.

Comment: I was able to use the first solution itself and get it for 1-2 widgets .

Comment: Please do try answering another question I had asked around 15 hrs back. Looks simple, but I am not sure why that is not working. Do have a look at it. Thanks